# Segue in UICollectoinView using Xcode 6

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6

I am new to Swift and iOS development.
I am trying to create a demo app which simply shows details of an item in a new scene when clicked.
I tried using Storyboard but I learned that One cannot create segues directly from cells in a storyboard because the `CollectionView` is populated dynamically through the data source.

So I tried using `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender` but clicking an item doesn't trigger anything. I have set the Identifier for the Segue in Storyboard. I can't figure out what's wrong (As I am pretty new and don't understand the complete flow yet).

My first class is `myFirstViewController.swift` and second is `mySecondViewController.swift`
Please help (Where should I put the **prepareForSegue**, **performSegue function**?)
I am using **xCode** 6 on **OS X Yosemite**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `myFirstViewController` class must implement the `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocol.

In InterfaceBuilder create a segue to your second viewController by ctrl-dragging from the *viewController1 icon* to the second viewController. Give that segue an identifier name in the property inspector.

In `myFirstViewController.swift`, implement the `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)`, there you can call `performSegueWithIdentifier` with your segue's identifier name.

Answer (score 0):

You can segue directly from a cell in storyboard. Simply right-click and drag from the cell in the storyboard to the detail view controller that you want to activate.

If you really don't want to do it that way. Then another option would be to right-click and drag from your main view controller to the detail view controller to create a generic segue. Then name the segue. After that, you can call perform segue in your `collectionView(collectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath)` method. (Make sure you connect your view controller to your collection view as a delegate for this method to get called.)

Either way, you need to write a `prepareForSegue(segue, sender)` method in your main view controller to pass the selected item to the detail view controller.

Good luck on your new learning adventure!